# Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wseverin/ppa/ubuntu focal Release when installing linsiid software

Tags: package-management, xubuntu, ppa

I ran the following comand in the jobstep for install the linssid software:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wseverin/ppa
```

Those are the result:

```
LinSSID is graphically and functionally similar to iwscanner (Linux) and Inssider (Microsoft™ Windows®). It is written entirely in C++ using Linux wireless tools, Qt5, and Qwt.
 Más información: https://launchpad.net/~wseverin/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Pulse [ENTRAR] para continuar o Ctrl+C para cancelar la adición.

Obj:1 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Des:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]      
Des:4 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wseverin/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease             
Ign:6 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                          
Obj:7 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco Release                            
Obj:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Des:9 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]   
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wseverin/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Des:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [29,0 kB]
Des:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [63,6 kB]
Des:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.464 B]
Des:14 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [279 kB]
Des:15 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [362 kB]
Des:17 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [944 B]
Des:18 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [10,4 kB]
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho             
E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/wseverin/ppa/ubuntu focal Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
```

Can someone help me whith that error 10: 404 IP not found?

Comment: You have to remove the added ppa. [This ppa](http://ppa.launchpad.net/wseverin/ppa/ubuntu/dists/) does not provide any software for focal.

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party sources; so all security checks are on you. A quick look shows an archive that doesn't provide support on releases past 2018/bionic,  so why would your check not have detected a 2020 or *focal* release has no support?  https://launchpad.net/~wseverin/+archive/ubuntu/ppa  & the lack of maintenance can be a warning sign

Comment: You don't need any ppa, you can install from default repositories in newer releases, take a look [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linssid&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).